# I get this error after the installation of kommunicate chat bot in the app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, kommunicate

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@label value=(login_2) from AndroidManifest.xml:4:9-32
> is also present at [io.kommunicate.sdk:kommunicateui:2.3.0] AndroidManifest.xml:25:9-41 value=(@string/app_name).
> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:3:4-40:19 to override.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 23s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: what happens when removing the package? also are you using the latest version of it? maybe try using other versions that might not have the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add `tools:replace="android:label"`in your application tag on Manifest wherever the android:label is used.